# Running window.print() on an Android browser

Tags: javascript, android, firefox, printing

Running window.print() on Firefox for Android gives error NS_ERROR_NOT_AVAILABLE:

I know there was a lot of talk about this in a few years ago and iOS was the only OS that supported print() as Google was concentrating on their cloud printing platform, but I read somewhere more current that the newer versions of Android do support print now. I still get this error when trying to print my html page from Firefox browser. I tried to install JS Print Status add-on, but it seemed to be impossible on my phone.

Does someone know if there is a way to print from browser with JS now in 2017 and has managed to do this successfully?